# Why Button click event works in all version but does not work in Pie?

Tags: android, android-9.0-pie

All my old apps are working fine in android. But during recent testing in the Android emulator with android Pie, I am stuck in the first page. I am not able to click. It shows on email field "Unverified Post".
I don't know what it means. So does anybody know what was updated in PIE?

I have checked the code but I can't find where the problem is.
And, what is "Unverified Post" that shows on email `Textview`?

**Code:**

```
findViewById(R.id.submit_btn).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        findViewById(R.id.submit_btn).setEnabled(false);
        register();
    }
});
```

**Image**

[image]

**java**

```
validateform()

@JohnJoe in there validateform() is         
private boolean validateForm() {
    boolean result = true;
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(firstNameEditText.getText().toString())) {
        firstNameEditText.setError("Required");
        result = false;
    } else if (firstNameEditText.getText().toString().length() < 3) {
        firstNameEditText.setError("Please enter first name");
        result = false;
    } else {
        firstNameEditText.setError(null);
    }
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(lastNameEditText.getText().toString())) {
        lastNameEditText.setError("Required");
        result = false;
    } else if (lastNameEditText.getText().toString().length() < 3) {
        lastNameEditText.setError("Please enter last name");
        result = false;
    } else {
        lastNameEditText.setError(null);
    }

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(emailEditText.getText().toString())) {
        emailEditText.setError("Required");
        //result = false;
    } else if (!isValidEmail(emailEditText.getText().toString())) {
        emailEditText.setError("Please enter valid email");
       // result = false;
    } else {
       // emailEditText.setError(null);
    }
    return result;
```

Comment: you should check your code and see what condition make it to return "_Unverified Post_".

Comment: @JohnJoe There is not single condition ever mention "Unverified Post Call"

Comment: it should has. Show us your register function.

Comment: @JohnJoe here Register Function   java private void register() {
        if (!validateForm()) {
            findViewById(R.id.submit_btn).setEnabled(true);
            return;
        }

Comment: when "Unverified Post" show? After submit button clicked or once you fill up the email?

Comment: @JohnJoe and Validateform() code on upper section edited Question not able to print in comment box

Comment: please edit your post by adding all the relevant code.

Comment: @JohnJoe when i click on submit button it's only appear on email. (but only not works in Pie other are working )

Comment: Try search "_Unverified Post Call_" in Android Studio. It must be written in somewhere else. Maybe in strings.xml or your current activity layout?

Comment: @JohnJoe  Searched Every where by using android search but shows "nothing Found"!

Comment: Impossible dude. Is the code written by you?

Comment: @JohnJoe actuallyi have written half not whole and this issue come in only Android 9.0

Comment: @JohnJoe I can Share this single code file it you want to look up?

Comment: maybe upload to github?

Comment: @JohnJoe give me id to appoint you code on github!

Comment: All changes in Android 9 could be found here: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-changes-all and here: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-changes-28
I suspect you're using cleartext traffic. Is there any HTTP request (not HTTPS) in `register()` or after it?

Comment: @RaviJK have you solved?

Comment: @JohnJoe yeah bro almost  solved but need to test in real devices... thanks

Comment: Add your solution as answer please

Comment: @SergeyGlotov Solution is Just removed email field verification!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you guys for clearing ways 
Just Removed Current Email Validation and replace with another method! not found the right solution for the now.